# Select rows from array of uuid when dealing with two tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have products and providers. Each product has an uuid and each provider has a list of uuid of products that they can provide.
How do I select all the products that a given (i.e. by provider uuid) provider can offer?

```
Products:
    +------+------+------+
    | uuid | date | name |
    +------+------+------+
    |    0 |    - |    - |
    |    1 |    - |    - |
    |   2  |    - |    - |
    +------+------+------+
Providers:
+------+----------------+
| uuid | array_products |
+------+----------------+
|    0 | [...]          |
|    1 | [...]          |
|   2  | [...]          |
+------+----------------+
```

Comment: What is a data type of the `array_products`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select p.name, u.product_uuid 
from products p
join
(
 select unnest(array_products) as product_uuid 
 from providers where uuid = :target_provider_uuid 
) u on p.uuid = u.product_uuid;
```

Please note however that your data design is not efficient and much harder to work with than a normalized one.